# AWS IOT node sdk gives ResourceNotFoundException for listThings and createThing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I'm trying to get details of the registered things and create new things. I get ResourceNotFoundException for both of them.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var iot = new AWS.Iot({
    endpoint: "https://XXXXXXXXXX.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    region: "us-east-1",
    accessKeyId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    secretAccessKey: "XXXXXXXXXX"
});

var params = {
    thingName: 'D02',
    attributePayload: {
        attributes: {
            'Org': 'Org2'
        },
        merge: false
    },
    thingTypeName: 'thing1'
};
iot.createThing(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});

 iot.listThings({}, function(err, data) {
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

As for the credentials, I created a new user in IAM. Set Programmatic access as Access Type and attached AWSIoTFullAccess permission.

Is there anything wrong here? What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it sorted out.

It was giving 404 or raising ResourceNotFoundException because endpoint was incorrect.  IoT constructor would have to be like this. Endpoint should be just `iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

```
var iot = new AWS.Iot({
    endpoint: "iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    region: "us-east-1",
    accessKeyId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    secretAccessKey: "XXXXXXXXXX"
});
```

Comment: The same problem troubled me for 2 hours! Where did you find out that endpoint should be *WITHOUT* a prefix? In all AWS documentation it says that endpoint is created with prefix :/

Comment: @errata Hi. Sorry for the delay. Yes it was very difficult to troubleshoot when the document itself is misleading. Found the endpoint from here. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#iot_region

Comment: Thanks for the link!